# Anonymous Pipe for IPC in windows app to communicate with each other C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pipe

I am currently researching IPC communication using anonymous pipe for the win form app in C#,
but I am not getting any type of proper reply for the windows app. So, please help me out on the anonymous pipe for sending data from parent to child (server to client).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use anonymous pipes? And why do you want to write your own implementation when there are many libraries for IPC available?

Comment: In [System.IO.Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes) you have [NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream) or [AnonymousPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeclientstream) (and the Server counterparts) -- In [System.IO.Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines) you have the [Pipe Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipe) (reader and writer)

Comment: Some interesting notes here: [Pipelines - a guided tour of the new IO API in .NET, part 1](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) and [Part - 2](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-2.html)

Comment: A `NamedPipeClientStream` is a simplified (managed/managed pipe) tool that it's very simple to use and quite efficient, if you simply need to communicate between two WinForms apps you have control over (you built).